# PHP: what is the convinient or enhanced code for searching a current file in directories?

Tags: php, image, search, path, directory

I have my code below. It searches the image in 2 directories and it will print the image if the image is found or it will not show the image if not found.

```
<?php
$file = 'testimage.png'; 

$dir = 
   [$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pathA/", 
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pathB/"];

foreach( $dir as $d )
{

    if( file_exists( $d . $file )) 
    {
        $image = $d . $file;    
    }

}

if(empty($image))
{
    $image = null;
}

$img = imagecreatefrompng($image);

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagePng($img);
?>
```

Can someone provide me a enchance or convinient way of a code above?

Comment: And what exactly don't you like about this code? I don't think there's something much more convenient for the task you have.

Comment: simplified? less "if statement"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the $image = null; as a default, so you don't have to check empty($image) and you can add a break to the loop, so you don't always have to look in both pathes, if you have already found it in the first path:

```
 $image = null;
 foreach( $dir as $d )
 {

    if( file_exists( $d . $file )) 
    {
        $image = $d . $file;    
        break; //Exit loop when the file is found
    }

 } 
 //Remove empty($image)-Check
```

You can't really simplify the check, because at some level you have to use a function like "file_exists" that returns if the file exists. And if you have different pathes, you also have to check until you find it (or it doesn't exist)

So: Your code is fine.

Comment: i can't put else statement after the if statement why? and thank you

Comment: same code as yours but you put it as $image = null; which it keeps variable $image = null; even the file is exist.

Comment: is it better to used while? than if? which is faster to execute?

Comment: Foreach the quickest - by far.
Check: http://www.phpbench.com/ for PHP Performance issues. It helps to write performant code.

Answer (score 0):

A much more convenient way of doing such things is using third-party libraries. If you are OK with that you can look into [Nette Finder](http://doc.nette.org/en/finder) or [Symfony Finder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html) (or any other similar library).

With Nette Finder the example then could look like this:

```
$images = iterator_to_array(Finder::findFiles($file)->in($dir));
$image = $images ? reset($images) : NULL;

$img = imagecreatefrompng($image->getPath());
// ...
```

If you have just this one script working with files, it would probably be an overkill. However, if you are working with files a little bit more it's definitely worth a try.

Comment: i dont't want to use third parties. is there another way without using 3rd parties in your code above?

Comment: Not really, your code is fine. I was thinking you find the PHP file-functions uncomfortable, that's why I pointed you to the 3rd party libs.